# UI not loading properly after adding SharePoint script files

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, office-365, internet-explorer

I have added following script files for like functionality in SharePoint .aspx page in SPD.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.runtime.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.search.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="reputation.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="init.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/> 
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
```

After adding these script file, my website UI is not getting loaded properly in Internet Explorer.
What could be the possible reasons?

I am using Office 365.
Below is the screenshot of the errors in the console[image]

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint?

Comment: Please clarify what is wrong. I've tried to paste your code into new sharepoint aspx page and page loaded properly. Do you have any errors in browser developer console? Could you attach an image?

Comment: I have updated my question and has attached screenshot of the error.